# flutter release app not showing thumbnail

Tags: flutter, dart, thumbnails, video-thumbnails, flutter-futurebuilder

In my app, I'm listing all the videos from phone storage. In gridview i'm showing all the videos. I'm futurebuilder as a parent for video_thumbnail widget. In emulator it working correctly and showing all the videos with thumbnail but when i'm taking build and running in my phone, it shows only circular progress bar.

[image: App Screenshot]

My Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';

class VideoWithThumbnail extends StatefulWidget {
   final String filePath;

   VideoWithThumbnail({@required this.filePath});
  
   @override
   _VideoWithThumbnailState createState() => _VideoWithThumbnailState();
  }

 class _VideoWithThumbnailState extends State<VideoWithThumbnail> {
    Future futureThumbnail;
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      futureThumbnail = getThumbnail();
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return FutureBuilder(
           future: futureThumbnail,
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState) {
                   return Image.memory(snapshot.data);
                } else {
                   return CircularProgressIndicator();
                 }
              },
           );
      }

 Future<Uint8List> getThumbnail() async {
   Uint8List unit8List = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
    video: widget.filePath,
    imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
    maxWidth:
      128, 
    quality: 25,
    );
   return unit8List;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to change it from connection.done to wating and change if condition ofcourse

Answer (score 2):

Your builder format is wrong and you did not specify the data type. This is how you are supposed to do it. You must always have a return at the end.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
       future: futureThumbnail,
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState) {
               return Image.memory(snapshot.data);
            } else {
               return CircularProgressIndicator();
             }
          },
       );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a permission you should use in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.
Android considers permissions itself when you run your application on debug mode.

Comment: I added Internet, Storage permission in Manifest file.